# Error when importing python igraph in OSX 10.10.5 by anaconda (libxml2.2.dylib)

Tags: python, macos, igraph, anaconda

I installed the python igraph library for anaconda following the directions in this thread [installing python igraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30262637/installing-python-igraph-anaconda-on-mac), So the C core library and the python package were successfully installed. However, when I tried to import the igraph library in python, I am getting the following error

```
>>> import igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from igraph._igraph import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so, 2): Library not loaded: libxml2.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so
  Reason: Incompatible library version: _igraph.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0
```

Looking for similar threads, I found a similar issue here [Installation of python igraph with lxml problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26981198/installation-of-igraph-on-python-distributed-by-anaconda-and-graphviz). However, there is not a clear way on how to solve this issue. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See point 1) in my answer to another (but related) question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26994150/156771

Comment: Hi @Tamás. I found all the occurrences of `libxml2*.dylib` and they are in `usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.2/lib/`, `usr/lib/`, `anaconda/lib`, `opt/local/lib` and `anaconda/pkgs/libxml2-2.9.0-1/lib` which have 12.2.0 10.9.0, 12.2.0, 12.2.0 and 12.0.0 version respectively. Based on the suggestion on your previous thread , should I changed the name of the file in `usr/lib/` which is the one that has the 10.9.0 version and leave the others as they are? Thank you.

Comment: No, exactly the opposite - try to get rid of those that have version `12.x`, recompile and then rename them back. The reason is that the linker obviously finds the one with version 10.9.0 when you try to import igraph, so if you renamed the one with version 10.9.0, then recompiled igraph, it would still be compiled with 12.0.0. (Also, `libxml2` with ABI version 10.9.0 seems to be the system-wide libxml2, so renaming it is dangerous anyway).

Comment: Hi @Tamás. I tried what you said before but it still complain about import igraph, it says `Reason: Incompatible library version: _igraph.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0.` I was wondering if it is related with the places at which installation is performed. I am using brew to compile and install the core `brew install igraph` and then `pip install python-igraph`. But it seem to be that the core is in `/usr/local/Cellar/igraph/0.7.1` and the python package in `/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/` Any suggestion?

Comment: I have added a proper answer below - let's continue the discussion there.

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda Python is weird - it ships with its own version of `libxml2` and when you run `pip install python-igraph`, igraph is probably linked against it. However, when you try to import igraph, the linker finds the system-wide `libxml2`, which has a lower ABI version, so that's why you see the error message.

The workaround for this is to ensure that during the *compilation* stage, Anaconda Python's `libxml2` is not picked up by the compiler. `setup.py` in the Python interface of igraph actually contains this workaround - it tries to detect when you are compiling igraph against Anaconda Python on OS X and then it tweaks the environment a bit to ensure that the linker picks up the right version of `libxml2`. However, this workaround is enabled only if you do *not* have the C core of igraph installed on your machine - the installer will download the C core, tweak the environment to work around Anaconda Python, then compile the C core and the Python interface together in one single step.

So, the solution is probably one of the following:

1. Move Anaconda Python's libxml2 out of the way (or maybe rename `xml2-config` from Anaconda Python's distribution temporarily), then compile and install the C core from Homebrew. (Use `brew unlink igraph`, `brew uninstall igraph`, `brew install igraph` to be on the safe side). Then you can run `pip install python-igraph`.
2. *Remove* Homebrew's igraph entirely and just run `pip install python-igraph` - it will download the C core, perform the necessary tweaks and then compile everything.

Comment: Hi @Tamás. I tried both proposed solutions but still I am getting `Reason: Incompatible library version: _igraph.so requires version 12.0.0 or later, but libxml2.2.dylib provides version 10.0.0.` In particular, for the first solution I did: 1. Rename `libxml2.2dylib` files that are in Anaconda folders, i.e., `anaconda/lib` and `anaconda/pkgs/libxml2-2.9.0-1/lib`; 2. `brew unlink igraph`; 3. `brew uninstall igraph`; 4. `brew install igraph`; 5. `pip install python-igraph`; 6. Rename back the `libxml2.2dylib` files that I changed in 1.

Comment: For the second solution, 1. Rename `libxml2.2dylib` files that are in Anaconda folders, i.e., `anaconda/lib` and `anaconda/pkgs/libxml2-2.9.0-1/lib`; 2. `brew unlink igraph`; 3. `brew uninstall igraph`; 4. `pip install python-igraph`; 5. Rename back the `libxml2.2dylib` files that I changed in 1. But still the same error. Am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Tamás. It seems to be that I have multiple versions of the `xml2-config` file. They are in `anaconda/pkgs/libxml2-2.9.2-0/bin`, `anaconda/pkgs/libxml2-2.9.2-1/bin`, `anaconda/bin` and `opt/local/bin` which of these should I need to rename? If I rename those files does not matter if the `libxml2.2dylib` are still there in anaconda folder? Thanks.

Comment: I would try renaming *all* of them - the goal here is to ensure that igraph picks up the system's libxml2 when you compile it, and igraph tries to detect where libxml2 is by running `xml2-config` first. If there is no `xml2-config`, it falls back to the system's libxml2.

Comment: Hi @Tamás. Thank for your help. I did the lastest changes, i.e., 1. uninstall `igraph` using pip, 2. rename the `libxml2.2.dylib` v12 files and their respective `xml2-config`, 3. install igraph using pip, 4. rename back all the mentiones files. However, now I got a different error:

Comment: import igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from igraph._igraph import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so, 2): Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address
  Referenced from: /Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/igraph/_igraph.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup, Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Please send me an email (see my homepage on my Stack Overflow profile - you can find my email address there after solving a CAPTCHA) - this discussion seems to be very specific to your particular setup and I don't think that the SO community would benefit from continuing the discussion there. (Also, I'd need lots of debug info at this point and it's hard to post here). I'll post the solution here once we find it.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue and installing/force linking `libxml2` worked for me:

```
brew install libxml2
brew link --force libxml2
```

Others also report the same solution and it appears to be working.